# Angular 7: Sending post request gives error 405 (Method not allowed)

Tags: angular, http, post, http-status-code-405

I have the CORS extension on Chrome and the GET request works fine but the POST request does not. I get the error "method not allowed" but since I have the CORS extension, according to the documentation, a POST request should work.

I tried to use optional headers as mentioned in another topic but the error remains.

I use this code:

```
send(id){
    let list = JSON.stringify(this.array)
    this.http.post(this.url + this.id, list)
         .subscribe(),
            error => console.log("Error: ", error)
    )
}
```

The error message in the browser console is:

> message:Http failure response for http://localhost:4000/...
>       name: "HttpErrorResponse"
>       ok: false
>       status: 405
>       statusText: "Method Not Allowed"

Comment: does the request work if you try outside the browser with `curl` or the like?

Comment: I just tried it with postman. I look up what curl is, thank you

Comment: Does it work with `Postman`? If so you don't need to try with `curl` the results should be the same. Please add the **excat exception text** from your browsers **console** to your question.

Comment: If it does not work with `Postman` it has nohting to do with `CORS` since thouse are a browser thing and ignored by `Postman`.

Answer (score 8):

this has probably nothing to do with `CORS`.

> 405 Method Not Allowed

is generally used to indicate that the **HTTP Method** (`POST` in your case) is not accepted by the server (for the target resource). Have a look at the response heades of the 405 - it should contain something like this

```
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD
```

---

ab bit suspicious is the fact that you append your token to the request URL (assuming that `this.currentUservalueToken` is used for authentication). "Normally" you would use the `Authorization` HTTP **header** for this.

try adding an `Authorization` header like this:

```
send(ordernummer){
    let arr = JSON.stringify(this.localeArray)

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer AADDFFKKKLLLL');

    this.http.post(this.url+ ordernummer + "/" + this.id, arr, {
        headers: headers
      }).subscribe(data => console.log("Successful"),
            error => console.log("Error: ", error)
    )
}
```

Comment: You are right and I looked uup the response header and there's no field containing 'Allow: GET, POST, HEAD'

Comment: or better yet use a `HttpInterceptor` to append the authorization bearer token on all requests

Comment: try the request in `Postman` w/o appending the *currentUservalueToken* in the URL. This should give you a 401 (Unauthorized) if so try using the token in Postmans "Auth" tab

Answer (score 0):

**.net core** sample for sending number array :

if you use [Route("deleteAllWithIds/{ids}")] you get this error : "405 Method Not Allowed" in browser console.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("deleteAllWithIds")]
public async Task<IActionResult> deleteAllWithIds([FromBody] List<int> ids)
{
}

public deleteAllWithIds(ids: number[]): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any[]>(this.baseUrl + '/deleteAllWithIds', ids);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for anyone - worth checking your that http request matches the Http request in the Controller.

service.ts

```
this.http.post(path)
```

controller.cs

```
[HttpPost("path")]
```